# Activity indicator after select cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uistoryboardsegue, uiactivityindicatorview

In my Swift app, I have a tableview, in which selecting a cell, takes you to a detail page, and the detail page takes time to load. I am trying to show an activity indicator as it loads. How can I do this? Right now, when a cell is selected, the activity indicator does not show.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)


        let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)


        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let data_id = self.ids[indexPath.row] as? Int {

            defaults.setValue("\(data_id)", forKey: "data_id")
            defaults.synchronize()

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showInfo", sender: self) 

        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `detailViewController` do the following

Add an activityIndicator

```
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width)/2, y: (self.view.frame.height)/3)
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
activityIndicator.color = UIColor.grayColor()
self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
```

In your `viewDidLoad` start the animation

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Now you will for sure load some data in some function or what you do, when all this is done, stop the animation in the last function you call

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```